# One number appears only once?

Tags: c++, project, multidimensional-array, sudoku

So I've been trying to write a function for which will generate numbers for a sudoku puzzle. This is what it looks like.

I'm kind of lost at the very last line... How can i check if one number only appears in one row and one column?

```
void generator (int row, int col){

    for (int i=0; i<9; i++){
        int randNum= (1+rand()%9);
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
            A[i][j]=randNum;
            //check if one number only appears once. 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it completely wrong.

You should simply fill the Sudoku according to the rules, starting from `1`.

After you have a valid Sudoku, switch the numbers randomly using a random permutation.

Do note that this is a pretty complex problem (if you include the actual Sudoku generation, not just the filled board) and you are most likely underestimating it.

Comment: @sis007 Many options. You can use `random_shuffle` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/

Answer (score 0):

I would add each random number to a vector. Then after each number is generated iterate through all the vector members to check for a value that already exists.